# php, how to output date in a fixed locale/language format?

Tags: php

In a php script, I need to output  a date in a fixed language,  something like `$date-> format('j F Y', 'it_IT')`.
I know that I may use:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'it_IT');
$dataItalian = strftime("%e %B %Y", strtotime($myDataObj->format('j F Y')));;
```

But `strftime` has been deprecated, and I do not see how I am supposed to do otherwise.

(I have php-intl installed).

Answer (score 0):

i think you should use IntlDateFormatter class.

See php manual here -> https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.intldateformatter.php

```
<?php 
function formatDate(Datetime $dateTime, $format = 3, $locale = 3 ): string{

    $fmt = new IntlDateFormatter('it_IT', 3, 3, 'Europe/Rome', 1, 'dd/MM/YYYY');
    return $fmt->format($dateTime);

  }

//an example with Datetime 'now' //

  $localZone = new DateTimeZone('Europe/Rome');
  $yourDate1 = new Datetime('now', $localZone);
  echo formatDate($date1);
```

i hope that will help you!

Comment: Thanks. An example would help.

Comment: Out of curiosity... Why use `3` instead of `IntlDateFormatter::SHORT`? The values of the constants are not even shown in the manual.

Comment: because my IDE offers this! that's all! :). but it's the same result and it's shorter to write.